# Meteor - Arrow Functions breaking #each loop in ES6

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6, meteor-blaze

I'm hoping I got the right area to ask for this...
Below is some code from two files I'm working on. When I change anything with '`this.`' in the function to an arrow function, the code no longer functions as expected.

Is someone able to explain what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to do something differently when using arrow functions? Am I using 'this.' incorrectly to begin with? Should I not be using arrow functions in this way?

Help is greatly appreciated.

**client/views/jobList.html**

```
{{#each jobs}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{jobID}}</td>
            <td>{{user.fullname}}</td>
            <td>{{product.type}}</td>
            <td>{{shortDesc}}</td>
            <td>{{formattedDate}}</td>
            <td>{{phone}}</td>
            <td>{{user.username}}</td>
            <td>{{jobType}}</td>
            <td>{{product.brand}}</td>
            <td>{{product.type}}</td>
            <td>{{product.model}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

**client/views/jobList.js**

```
Template.jobList.helpers({
    jobs: ()=> Jobs.find({}, {sort: {jobDate: 1}}),

    formattedDate: function() { // Changing this to arrow function breaks functionality
        let d = this.jobDate;
        let e = formatDate(d);
        return e;
    },
    shortDesc: function () { // Changing this to arrow function breaks functionality
        if (this.description.length > 40) {
            return this.description.substr(0, 50) + '...';
        } else {
            return this.description
        }
    },
    jobID: function () { // Changing this to arrow function breaks functionality
        let a = this.jobNum;
        let e = this.jobType.substr(0, 1);
        return e + a
    }
});
```

Comment: Please, show us your arrow function that does not work? Best way for us to tell you if it is correct ;)

Comment: if I change any of the methods which contain `this` in the helper to an arrow function....Edited it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the fundamental things about arrow functions is that they inherit (*close over*) the `this` in the context in which they're created. Your code relies on `this` being set by the way the function is called, so arrow functions aren't a good choice there.

Here's an illustration of the difference and the problem:

```js
var obj = {
    foo: () => {
        console.log("foo: this.prop:", this.prop);
    },
    bar: function() {
        console.log("bar: this.prop:", this.prop);
    },
    prop: "the property"
};
obj.foo(); // Doesn't show `prop` because `this` != `obj`
obj.bar(); // Does show `prop` because `this` == `obj`
```

Comment: Ok that's along the lines of what I was starting to think.
So, in these instances I should just use the standard function declaration?

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated :)

Comment: @jERCle: Those aren't function declarations (they're function *expressions*), but yes, use a standard (non-arrow) functions. You can make them more concise if you like by using method syntax in your object initializer (which is another new thing in ES2015): http://pastie.org/10874562.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. Still new to this.
Thank you, I didn't think of using that syntax at all.

Comment: @jERCle: Hey, it's brand-new, not surprising not to think of it. :-)

Comment: I think it may have come out before I started coding. I only started learning near the end of last year. However, I haven't really got into ES6 as much as I'd like yet. I'll get there in the end. Thank you again :)